# Format specifier behavior in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char test1[10];
    char test2[10];
    sprintf(test1,"%d",20);
    sprintf(test2,"%d",3);
    printf("%d\n",strcmp(test1,test2));

    sprintf(test1,"%2d",20);
    sprintf(test2,"%2d",3);
    printf("%d\n",strcmp(test1,test2)); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
OUTPUT:-
-1
 1
```

I am able to understand the first one since lexicographically 2 is less than 3 but I am unable to understand what happens in the second case.

Comment: show the output of your program. and clarify more your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first example you are reading it as '20' and '3' -> So not equal.

In second exmple you are reading it as '20' and ' 3'-> note space.

Its not 2 vs 3. It is 20 vs 3. `%d` will read whole string. You may want to check with `%1d`

Return from strcmp

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the
>   strings: A zero value indicates that both strings are equal. A value
>   greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not
>   match has a greater value in str1 than in str2; And a value less than
>   zero indicates the opposite.

Comment: how is the space added?Coudldnt be it like '3 '?

Comment: Space is added because %2d is forcing it to format that way. But as it is single digit, one extra space will be added at start.

If you add %-2d (note - sign), space will be added at the end.

Comment: thanks ,yes it is clear

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the padding this way, you're adding space as padding. Try:

```
sprintf(test2, "%02d", 3);
```

if you want to output "03".

In the first case, you're comparing "20" with "3". The first characters that don't match are 2 and 3. 3 is larger, so the output is -1. In the second case, the first characters that don't match are 2 and space. Space, being 32, is smaller than '2' (ascii 50). Hence the output is 1.